Chess Arrangements
What are the number of arrangements (of a single row of 8 pieces) such that the following restrictions are followed:

The King is between 2 rooks and the king must be (adjacent) next to the queen.
Bishops must be on oppositely coloured squares.

How many arrangements are there? I got 320 but apparently the answer is 248? I got 320 by first multiplying 4*4 (4 squares per bishop) leaving 6 remaining squares. From these 6 there are 40 ways (by casework) to choose the ways for the two rooks and king and queen to be arranged. This will leave only 2 more ways to choose the knights but we need to divide by 2! to avoid double counting the knights arrangements. 4 * 4 * 40 / 2! = 8 * 40 = 320.

The bishops need to be on two places with different colours. As the kind and the queen need to be next to each other, both together occupy exactly one place of every colour.

Can you elaborate on the "40 ways (by casework)"?  In particular, I expect that the number of ways would be dependent on which 2 squares the bishops are on. Can you justify why it would always be the same?

You don't reveal your casework to us, but I suspect you are counting arrangements of the form KBBQ, which are not allowed.

Observation: After the rooks and the royalty have been placed: If the rooks are on the same color, there will be three remaining squares of one color, and one of the other color; and so there will be $3$ ways to place the bishops. On the other hand, if the rooks are on opposite colors, there will be two squares remaining of each color; and so there will be $4$ ways to place the bishops.
Then condition on the number of empty spaces between the rooks (before the other pieces have been placed):
Case A: Two empty spaces between rooks. Note: rooks are on opposite colors, so there will be $4$ ways to place the bishops as noted above.
Place the rooks: 5 ways
Place the royalty between the rooks: 2 ways (KQ or QK).
Place the bishops: 4 ways.
Place the knights: 1 way
Total for Case A: 40 ways

Case B: Three empty spaces between the rooks. Note: Rooks are on same color, so there will be $3$ ways to place the bishops.
Place the rooks: 4 ways.
Place the royalty: 4 ways (KQx, QKx, xKQ, xQK).
Place the bishops: 3 ways.
Place the knights: 1 way.
Total for Case B: 48 ways.

Case C: Four empty spaces between the rooks (rooks on opposite colors).
Place the rooks: 3 ways.
Place the royalty: 6 ways.
Place the bishops: 4 ways.
Place the knights: 1 way.
Total for Case C: 72 ways.

Case D: Five empty spaces between the rooks: (Similar analysis).
Total for Case D: 48 ways.

Case E: Six empty spaces between the rooks: (Similar analysis).
Total for Case E: 40 ways.  

Grand total: There are $40+48+72+48+40=248$ legal placements under the given constraints.

A lot harder than the other answer, but an alternative way to get to the same number.
We could condition on where the king is. There are $6$ place where we can put the king to respect the condition about the two rooks. Those $6$ positions are pair-wise symetric. We have three possibilities to examine. Once the king is place, we'll look for the queen and the two rooks.
If the two rooks are on the same color, there is $3$ ways to place the bishops. If the rook are on different color, there is $4$ ways to place the bishops.
King in postion A2
Easiest case. A rook has to be on A1 and the queen has to be on A3. Then, there are $2$ choices where the rooks are on the same color and $3$ choices where they are on different color.
$$\text{total}_{A2} = 2\times 3 + 3\times 4 =18$$
King in postion A3
Sligthly more complicated. If the queen is on A2, same case as above ($18$ possibilities).
If the queen is on A4, The left rook has $2$ choices. In every cases, the right rook has $2$ choices for being the same color, and $2$ choices for being different color. Adding the bishops, we get
$$\text{total}_{A3} = 18 + 2\times(2\times 3 + 2\times 4) = 46$$
King in postion A4
More complicated. If the queen is on A3, same case as King A3 - Queen A4 ($28$ possibilities).
If the queen is on A5, The left rook has $3$ choices. We'll split in two case, odd ($2$ choices) and even ($1$ choice)
The left rook is odd, there is $1$ choice the right rook is also odd and $2$ choices it is even.
$$2\times (1\times 3 + 2\times 4)=22$$
The left rook is even, there is $2$ choice the right rook is also even and $1$ choice it is odd.
$$1\times (2\times 3 + 1\times 4)=10$$
$$\text{total}_{A4} = 28 + 22 + 10 = 60$$
Conclusion
Multiplying to total by $2$ for symetry we have
$$2\times(18+46+60) = 248$$
